# sql query to display the input data

Tags: sql-server

I want a SQL query to display the following data

**Input Data:**

```
ID  GroupID     Data
 1     1        Hello
 2     1        Null
 3     1        Null
 4     1        World
 5     2        Niladri
 6     2        XXX
 7     2        Null
 8     2        PPP
 9     2        Null
10     2        Null
11     2        Null
12     2        LLL
```

as

**Output Data:**

```
GroupID   MergedData
   1          Hello2World   
   2          NiladriXXX1PPP3LLL
```

I need to group the data on `GroupID` and display the result as Hello2World

```
-->Hello is related to GroupID 1
-->2 is count of NULLS
-->World is related to GroupID 1
```

Similarly for GroupID 2.

Kindly suggest?

Thanks

Comment: Yawn, couldn't understand a thin from your post. ;P

Comment: I edited your post; please take care when formatting so that others may have a chance to understand you :-)

Comment: You might want to have a look a the (so far) single answer in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6435959/problem-in-counting-nulls-and-then-merging-them-with-the-existing-rows).

Answer (score 0):

As you did not mention your DBMS, this is a solution for PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT groupid, 
       string_agg(temp_data,'')
FROM (
  SELECT id,
         groupid, 
         data,
         CASE 
           WHEN data IS NULL 
              THEN cast(max(rn) over (partition by groupid, data) as varchar)
           ELSE data
         END AS temp_data,
         row_number() over (partition by groupid, data) as group_rn
  FROM (
    SELECT id,
           groupid,
           data,
           CASE 
             WHEN data IS NULL 
                THEN row_number() over (partition by groupid,data)
             ELSE NULL
           END AS rn
    FROM foo
  ) t1
  ORDER BY id
) t2 
WHERE group_rn in (0,1)
GROUP BY groupid
```

If your DBMS supports ANSI windowing functions and has something similar like the string_agg() function then this should be portable to your DBMS as well.